# Cannot Compile base MIBs IE RFC 1407

Tags: opennms

When trying to compile some base mib IE RFC 1407-MIB. I get the error

> Cannot find imported symbol OBJECT-TYPE in module /opt/opennms/share/mibs/pending/RFC1407-MIB%20DEFINITIONS.mib, Source: RFC1407-MIB%20DEFINITIONS.mib, Row: 8, Col: 24

The code it is bombing on is

```
IMPORTS
                   Gauge
                           FROM RFC1155-SMI
                   DisplayString, transmission
                           FROM RFC1213-MIB
                   OBJECT-TYPE
                           FROM RFC-1212;
```

It doesn't like "object type".  Now RFC-1212 has been compiled and in the list of mibs. Anybody find a work around to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use this 1212 version:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NationalAssociationOfRealtors/UPSMonitor/master/RFC-1212-MIB.txt

Also make sure RFC1407 MIB uses the correct title:

In RFC1407 MIB:

```
OBJECT-TYPE
  FROM RFC1212-MIB;
```

IN RFC1212 MIB

`RFC1212-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN`